# UICollectionView animate cells in initially

Tags: ios, animation, transform, uicollectionview

I present a view controller with a uicollectionview. I want the cells to animate in from the top.

My layout is a sublclass of flowlayout, so I override this method:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *) initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat height = [self collectionViewContentSize].height;
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -height, 0);
    return attributes;
}
```

It almost works, but i see the cells appear (flash) momentarily on the screen before they animate in.

Any ideas why they appear in their final location before the transform is applied, and how I might prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the transform, change the center:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *) initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGPoint c = attributes.center;
    c.y -= self.collectionViewContentSize.height;
    attributes.center = c;
    return attributes;
}
```

Changing the transform can always cause problems with determining visibility, because doing so invalidates the `frame` property.